# Finding the listening port of previous command

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to find the listening port of previous command, let's say I have a development server of Django and I use following command to run the development server:

```
./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Now I want to use `|` or `&` to get the listening port of that command, let's say something like:

```
./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000 & lsof -Pn -i4 | grep $!
```

I'm not sure how to write this command to get the listening port. In this case it's `8000`.

Comment: How will the "listening port" be determined? Is it `8000` in your above case or how is it identified?

Comment: @Inian yes, it's `8000` in that case.

Comment: So if  I understand right, you want to run command as `./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000 & lsof -Pn -i4` and get the port as `8000`?

Comment: @Inian exactly but it's not important to use `lsof` or any other commands to get the listening ports. all I want to do is finding the listening port of `./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: The way it's written it is likely the lsof command will be run before the other command has started.

Comment: @123 right, then how can we refactor that?

Comment: How long does the command run for? Just wait a second before running lsof?

Comment: @123 hmm, i see. it takes 2-3 seconds for the dev server to be ready. I thought the command after `&` will be executed when the previous one is completed ..

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani If your not interested in the same command, you use use the command "ss"  or "netstat" to find the listening sockets and grep with program name.

Comment: @ParthibanN `netstat` suits better. then what would the complete command be?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani `netstat -l -p --numeric-ports | grep manage.py | <Command to extract the port from according column>`

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani `&` runs it in the background...